# Checking if a button has been pressed in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

credit = 0
coins = 0
choice = 0


credit1 = 0
coins = 0
prices = [200,150,160,50,90]
item = 0
i = 0
temp=0
n=0
choice1 = 0
choice2 = 0

credit1 = 0
coins = 0
prices = [200,150,160,50,90]
item = 0
i = 0
temp=0
n=0
choice1 = 0
choice2 = 0

def insert():
    insert = Tk()

    insert.geometry("450x250")
    iLabel = Label(insert, text="Enter coins.[Press Buttons]").grid(row=1, column=1)

    tenbutton = Button(insert, text="10p").grid(row=2, column=1)
    twentybutton = Button(insert, text="20p").grid(row=3, column=1)
    fiftybutton = Button(insert, text="50p").grid(row=4, column=1)
    poundbutton = Button(insert, text="£1").grid(row=5, column=1)
```

I am creating a program that simulates a vending machine.
How would I tell Python to 'check' if  A button has been pressed?
In pseudocode it would be:

```
if tenbutton is pressed:
   Add 10p to credit
```

How would I write in Python "if tenbutton is pressed"? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It's simple, define a function which will be called after button press. Like so:

```
def addCredit():
    global credit
    credit+=10
```

And then assign this simple function to your button:

```
tenbutton = Button(insert, text="10p", command=addCredit).grid(row=2, column=1)
```

By the way, your code is badly asking for a `class` somewhere. Using so many globals is generally a bad practice. Another nitpick is `from tkinter import *`, it destroys readability. I'd suggest `import tkinter as tk`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `command` to your Tkinter `Button` widget that will callback a function:

```
def tenbuttonCallback():
    global credit
    credit += 10

tenbutton = Button(insert, text="10p", command=tenbuttonCallback)
tenbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

See: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 4):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()


def fun(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("button 1", "button 1 used")
    elif arg == 2:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("button 2", "button 2 used")
    elif arg == 3:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("button 3", "button 3 used")
    elif arg == 4:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("button 4", "button 4 used")


b1 = Button(root, text="Quit1", command=lambda: fun(1))
b1.pack()
b2 = Button(root, text="Quit2", command=lambda: fun(2))
b2.pack()
b3 = Button(root, text="Quit3", command=lambda: fun(3))
b3.pack()
b4 = Button(root, text="Quit4", command=lambda: fun(4))
b4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```